# Changing viewport of datagrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollbar, viewport

I need to change viewport of datagrid to maximum so all rows are propagated in constructor. So I used Scrollview with row height set to auto.

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid>

        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

This propagates all controls but now when I use scrollbar it also moves header row. I need that the scrollbar will effect only datagrid.

Answer (score 1):

I dont understand this statement

> ... need to change viewport of datagrid to maximum so all rows are
>   propagated in constructor. So I used Scrollview with row height set to
>   auto...

... where is the `Viewport` setting in the code? Also what is this `constructor`? Your terminologies are confusing....

However I can **assume** what you want is the datagrid to fully render its rows (without extra space below rows) and occupy that entriely over the grid panel. But because you have used a scroll viewer abone grid, it will scroll datagrid headers as well.

If you use "Snoop" you will find that wpf datagrid has a scroll viewer as its visual child and it has a `Grid` panel in its own template, there the `ScrollContentPresenter` is under a `Grid.Row` which has `RowDefinition` that has `Height` as asterick (*).

Using visual children extraction method given below, accesss that Grid descendent and change its height to auto.

```
  (GetVisualChild<Grid>(myDataGrid)).RowDefintions[1].Height="Auto"
```

Method to snoop through all children of a parent...

```
    static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
              Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
              child = v as T;
              if (child == null) child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
              if (child != null) break;
        }

        return child;
    }
```

**The XAML way**

Override the dataGrid Control template...

```
   <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
       <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
       <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
              SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
        <ScrollViewer   Focusable="false"
                        Name="DG_ScrollViewer">
          <ScrollViewer.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/> <!--This changed to Auto from '*'-->
                  <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--Left Column Header Corner -->
                <Button Command="{x:Static dg:DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                        Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}, Path=CellsPanelHorizontalOffset}"
                        Template="{StaticResource SelectAllButtonTemplate}"
                        Focusable="false"
                        Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static dg:DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dg:DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}}" />
                <!--Column Headers-->
                <dgp:DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Column="1" 
                                                   Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                   Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}, Path=HeadersVisibility, Converter={x:Static dg:DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static dg:DataGridHeadersVisibility.Column}}"/>

                <!--DataGrid content-->
                <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}" />

                <ScrollBar Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                         Orientation="Vertical"
                                         Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                         ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}"
                                         Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                                         Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                <Grid Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
                  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type dg:DataGrid}}, Path=NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ScrollBar Grid.Column="1"
                             Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar"
                             Orientation="Horizontal"
                             Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}"
                             ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}"
                             Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=OneWay}"
                             Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>

                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </ScrollViewer.Template>
          <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
        </ScrollViewer>
      </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
       </Setter>
   </Style>
```

Comment: Thank you. You understood my intention. Is it possible to do that in XAML?

Comment: If you insist in XAML, then you will have to override the entire `DataGrid` template to make a simple change like that. Are you ok with that? If so then see my edited reply above...

Comment: I implemented the first way and also enabled vertical scroll but when data is loaded the scroll becomes disabled and I can't use it.